# vertical carousel renderscript

Tags: android, carousel, renderscript

I need some help with the CarouselExample that can be checked out using this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip). I want to make it spin vertically. I found a method in the .rs file called getMatrixForCard where the transformations on the matrix of the cards is done. Here is the method:

```
static bool getMatrixForCard(rs_matrix4x4* matrix, int i, bool enableSway, bool   
enableCardMatrix)
{
float theta = cardPosition(i);
float swayAngle = getSwayAngleForVelocity(velocity, enableSway);
rsMatrixRotate(matrix, degrees(theta), 0, 1, 0);
rsMatrixTranslate(matrix, radius, getVerticalOffsetForCard(i), 0); 
/* rsMatrixTranslate(matrix, 0, radius, 0);*/
float rotation = cardRotation + swayAngle;
if (!cardsFaceTangent) {
  rotation -= theta;
}
rsMatrixRotate(matrix, degrees(rotation), 0, 1, 0);
bool stillAnimating = false;
if (i == animatedSelection) {
    float3 scale;
    stillAnimating = getAnimatedScaleForSelected(&scale);
    rsMatrixScale(matrix, scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
}
// TODO(jshuma): Instead of ignoring this matrix for the detail texture, use card 
bounding box
if (enableCardMatrix) {
    rsMatrixLoadMultiply(matrix, matrix, &cards[i].matrix);
}
return stillAnimating;
}
```

So i guessed that changing the values of x with y from this line, would make it work.

```
rsMatrixTranslate(matrix, radius, getVerticalOffsetForCard(i), 0);
```

But it does not. Please if someone has checked this example and knows how to help me and make the carousel vertical, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you have done the vertical Carousel?

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to change in this function, you need to change in some other params

in the **carousel.rs** file replace

```
static const float3 cardVertices[4] = {
        { -1.0, -1.0, 0.0 },
        { 1.0, -1.0, 0.0 },
        { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
        {-1.0, 1.0, 0.0 }
};
// Default camera
static PerspectiveCamera camera = {
        {2,2,2}, // from
        {0,0,0}, // at
        {0,1,0}, // up
        25.0f,   // field of view
        1.0f,    // aspect
        0.1f,    // near
        100.0f   // far
};
```

with

```
static const float3 cardVertices[4] = {
        { 0.0, -1.0, -1.0 },
        { 0.0, -1.0, 1.0 },
        { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 },
        { 0.0, 1.0, -1.0 }
};

static PerspectiveCamera camera = {
        {2,2,2}, // from
        {0,0,0}, // at
        {0,1,0}, // up
        40.0f,   // field of view
        1.0f,    // aspect
        0.1f,    // near
        100.0f   // far
};
```

and in the **CarouselTestActivity.java** change

```
private static final int CARD_SLOTS = 56;
```

to

```
private static final int CARD_SLOTS = 30;
```

and change **onCreate()** to be as follow

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.carousel_test);
    mView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    mView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    mPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    final Resources res = getResources();

    mHelper = new LocalCarouselViewHelper(this);
    mHelper.setCarouselView(mView);
    mView.setSlotCount(CARD_SLOTS);
    mView.createCards(INCREMENTAL_ADD ? 1: TOTAL_CARDS);
    mView.setVisibleSlots(SLOTS_VISIBLE);
    mBorder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.border);
    mView.setDefaultBitmap(mBorder);
    mView.setLoadingBitmap(mBorder);
    mView.setBackgroundColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    mView.setRezInCardCount(3.0f);
    mView.setFadeInDuration(250);
    mView.setVisibleDetails(VISIBLE_DETAIL_COUNT);
    mView.setDragModel(CarouselView.DRAG_MODEL_CYLINDER_INSIDE);

    // New settings
    mView.setStartAngle((float) -(11.7f*Math.PI / 10));
    mView.setVisibleDetails(6);
    mView.setRowCount(3);
    mView.setRadius(10f);
    float mEye[] = { 2f, 0f, 0f };
    float mAt[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    float mUp[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    mView.setLookAt(mEye, mAt, mUp);
    mView.setCardsFaceTangent(true);

    if (INCREMENTAL_ADD) {
        mView.postDelayed(mAddCardRunnable, 2000);
    }

    mGlossyOverlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.glossy_overlay);
}
```

the output will be as follow
[image: Vertical Carousel]

Comment: I already made the vertical carousel, but thank u very much for replying. There are not many people who answer my renderscript questions. If I have time, I will check this out.

Comment: how did you do it without the renderscript ??

Comment: @Hakem, where do you find the 3d carousel source? I don't see it under <sdk_root>/samples/android-11/RenderScript like it says on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Comment: you can find it in this link http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip

Comment: @Hakem, Can you please advise on how to fill from left to right instead of the opposite?  Also, in portrait mode the final column at each end is cut off.

Comment: how to modify the render script to make the image rotate like the one in this link. http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-3d-carousel.html. Can u help me with this Hakem Zaied

Comment: I don't think it is possible with this library, I even think that google doesn't support this carousel any more.