# Wall carousel like youtube

Tags: android, renderscript

I have to create a 3d wall carousel like you tube with varying number of rows(1,2 or 3). I got it using [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) example and modifying few variables.

```
I have to change the cardVertices(given below) in Carousel.rs to change the size of    the cards in the carouselview. I am not sure how to do it dynamically.

static const float3 cardVertices[4] = {
   { 0.0, -1.0, -1.0},
    { 0.0, -1.0, 1.0 },
   { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 },
    {0.0, 1.0, -1.0 }
};
```

Now I want to re-size the card  depending on number of rows in the same project. If the row is one then I want the card size to be large, if it is 2 then set the card size smaller.
I can achieve this in separate projects, but I want the result (I cannot upload the images to show hw the result should look like)
in the same project.

Please help me as this is achieved using renderscript, and I have little knowledge on rendescript. Any help Appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at this link. I think the answer provided in this link should help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018572/vertical-carousel-renderscript. I hope this is exactly what you are looking for.